# Create a random unique 6 digit number as custom field for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-field, loop, post-meta

I use the following function to create a random unique 6 digit number and save it in a custom post type meta field.

I am unsure about the use of `rewind_posts()` inside a while loop. The idea is that it checks if the `$random` number already exists inside any of the existing custom posts. If it exists it generates a new random number and checks again against all custom posts.

```
function create_random_unique_id() {

  // Create random 6 digit number
  $random   = substr( rand() * 900000 + 100000, 0, 6 );

  // Get all Custom Posts  
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

  // For each Custom Post, check if $random matches $cpt_id
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {

    $loop->the_post();
    $cpt_id = get_post_meta ( get_the_id(), 'id', true );

    // If $random matches $subscriber_id assign a different random 6 digit number
    if ( $cpt_id == $random ) {
      $random = substr( rand() * 900000 + 100000, 0, 6 );
      rewind_posts();
    }

  }

  return $random;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This quite an expensive operation what you are doing, and IMHO wrong worksflow as well. What you want to do is, is the following

- Get all the `meta_value`s from the specific `meta_key` you need.
- You can then check the random number against the values returned from a specific `meta_key`

Here is a very basic idea in code: (*Credit to Chinmoy Paul from pwdtechnology.com for the code. Code is commented for easy understanding*)

The following goes into `functions.php`

```
/**    
 * Description: Getting all the values associated with a specific custom post meta key, across all posts
 * Author: Chinmoy Paul
 * Author URL: http://pwdtechnology.com
 *
 * @param string $key Post Meta Key.
 *
 * @param string $type Post Type. Default is post. You can pass custom post type here.
 *
 * @param string $status Post Status like Publish, draft, future etc. default is publish
 *
 * @return array
 */
function get_unique_post_meta_values( $key = '', $type = 'post', $status = 'publish' ) 
{
    global $wpdb;
    if( empty( $key ) )
        return;
    $res = $wpdb->get_col( 
        $wpdb->prepare( 
            "SELECT DISTINCT pm.meta_value 
            FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p 
            ON p.ID = pm.post_id
            WHERE pm.meta_key = '%s'
            AND p.post_status = '%s'
            AND p.post_type = '%s'", 
            $key, 
            $status, 
            $type 
        ) 
    );
    return $res;
}
```

Now, to get a specific array of meta values from a given `meta_key` from a specific `post_type` and `post_status`, you can try the following

```
// Get ids to exclude
$ids_to_exclude = get_unique_post_meta_values(
    'id', // This is our meta_key to get values from
    'MY_POST_TYPE', // This is the name of your custom post type
    'POST_STATUS' // Any other post status except publish as publish is default
);

/**
 * Generate a unique id
 * Thanks to Gautam3164 for the code
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17109530/1908141
 */
do {   
    // This is taken as is from your code in question
    $random   = substr( rand() * 900000 + 100000, 0, 6 );
} 
while( in_array( $random, $ids_to_exclude ) );
echo $random;
```

### EDIT

You can put everything together in one fully functional function.

```
/**    
 * Description: Get a random unique 6 number id for any given meta_key
 *
 * @param string $key Post Meta Key.
 *
 * @param string $type Post Type. Default is post. You can pass custom post type here.
 *
 * @param string $status Post Status like Publish, draft, future etc. default is publish
 *
 * @return array
 */
function get_unique_random_value( 
    $key = '', 
    $type = 'post', 
    $status = 'publish' 
) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Check if we have a meta_key before continuing, if not, return false
    if( empty( $key ) )
        return false;

    $res = $wpdb->get_col( 
        $wpdb->prepare( 
            "SELECT DISTINCT pm.meta_value 
            FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p 
            ON p.ID = pm.post_id
            WHERE pm.meta_key = '%s'
            AND p.post_status = '%s'
            AND p.post_type = '%s'", 
            $key, 
            $status, 
            $type 
        ) 
    );
    // Check if we actually have an array of values, if not, return false
    if ( !$res )
        return false;

    /**
     * Generate a unique id
     * Thanks to Gautam3164 for the code
     * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17109530/1908141
     */
    do {   
        // This is taken as is from your code in question
        $random   = substr( rand() * 900000 + 100000, 0, 6 );
    } 
    while( in_array( $random, $res ) );
    return $random;
}
```

Then you can use it as follow

```
$random_id = get_unique_random_value (
    'id', // This is our meta_key to get values from
    'MY_POST_TYPE', // This is the name of your custom post type
    'POST_STATUS' // Any other post status except publish as publish is default
);
echo $random_id;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @PieterGoosen, this looks great. I had never come across a usecase where I had to do a direct call to the WP Database. But this is obviously way more effective. I will try it out later to check if it works as intented

Comment: My pleasure, hope you get this working. Good luck :-)

Comment: Works perfect. You just forgot a closing ) in the last while loop :)

Comment: My pleasure, thanks for the note on the error, will fix in. Many thanks. Enjoy :-)